# Is it normal to overworking of just one CPU when using openMP

Tags: linux, cpu, top, parallel-processing

When I use OpenMP in FORTRAN to parallelize a program on linux, ' top' command show me just one processor working ~%800 instead of ~%100 x 8 processors. Is it a expected situation ?

Comment: Turn off Hyperthreading in your bios and see if you still get 800%. I'm guessing you have a 4 core processor with each having 2 threads, ergo "8 processors".

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a summation of all threads in the process. You have to tell top to display individual threads. You can do it either by calling  `top -H` or using the `H` interactive command during top execution.